# The math and logic of video games

Tags: reference-request

Is there a paper or text somewhere where someone axiomatizes the concept of video or computer games and makes definitions and proves theorems? I would love to see such a text. It would be quite something.

Comment: Dynamics of [Pong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pong) world, perhaps?  [Asteroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroids_(video_game))?  (I'm dating myself here...)

Comment: It has been far too long. You must write it yourself. Carry on, my wayward son.

Comment: Of games in general, or of a specific game?

Comment: Of games in general.

Comment: _Computer_ games?  Not to the best of my knowledge - what would the axioms be?  But for games in general, there's both Nash-style 'optimizing' game theory ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory ) and Combinatorial Game Theory ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_game_theory ), which is used to study a number of pencil-and-paper games. (And naturally, there's a ton of mathematics _in_ video games, particularly vector mathematics and differential equations for representation and simulation.)

Comment: I don't understand the question. "Games in general" aren't math, and I don't know of anything that has an axiomatic treatment except math.